# How do I construct JSON request for form parameter using requests library?

Tags: python-3.x, api

I am trying to hit an endpoint with the raw request (CURL) as stated below :

```
!curl -i -X 'POST' "END_POINT" \
--form "api_key=xxxxx" \
--form "image= LOCAL_PATH_TO_IMAGE"
```

I tried using requests library of Python but I do not know how to construct the JSON request for the above.

```
def fetch_details(API_KEY, IMAGE_PATH, SERVICE_URL):

        form = {
            "api_key": API_KEY , 
            "image":  open(IMAGE_PATH,'rb')
        }
        header = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        url = SERVICE_URL
        #response = requests.post(url, json = json.dumps(form), headers=header)
        response = requests.post(url, json = json.dumps(json.loads(jsonpickle.encode(form))), headers=header)
        if response.status_code != 200:
          print('There is an error and the error is : ', response.text)
        else:
          attributes = response.json()
          print(attributes)
```

1. I expect a JSON response for the above request but the output is "There is an error and the error :  Server Error (500)"
2. The --form "image" parameter should contain the binary representation of the image.

Comment: Try `open(IMAGE_PATH,'rb').read()`. Also, I'm not sure what you tried to do with `json.dumps(json.loads(jsonpickle.encode(form))))`

Comment: @DeepSpace I was getting JSON serializable error if I do not do json.dumps(json.loads(jsonpickle.encode(form))))

Comment: It was because you used `open(IMAGE_PATH,'rb')` instead of `open(IMAGE_PATH,'rb').read()`. You tried to serialize the file object instead of its content

Comment: @DeepSpace Even if I use open(IMAGE_PATH,'rb').read() I am getting "TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable"